# Web API en ASP.NET con OData - Problema en la vista

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, odata

Tengo una *Web API* en *ASP.NET* con *OData* y puedo consumir sin problemas del servicio, pero no consigo que la vista me imprima una tabla. Me estoy iniciando con *.NET* y con *MVC*.

Modelo:

```
namespace exchange_rates
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class CurrentValue
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Currency { get; set; }
        public double Rate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controlador:

```
namespace exchange_rates.Controllers
{
    public class CurrentValuesController : ODataController    
    {
        private db_test_bce_Entities db = new db_test_bce_Entities();

        // GET: odata/CurrentValues
        [EnableQuery]
        public IQueryable<CurrentValue> GetCurrentValues()
        {
            return db.CurrentValues;
        }

        // GET: odata/CurrentValues(5)
        [EnableQuery]
        public SingleResult<CurrentValue> GetCurrentValue([FromODataUri] int key)
        {
            return SingleResult.Create(
                db.CurrentValues.Where(currentValue => currentValue.Id == key)
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Código del archivo **WebApiConfig.cs**:

```
namespace exchange_rates
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.EntitySet<CurrentValue>("CurrentValues");
            config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());
        }
    }
}
```

Vista:

```
@model IEnumerable<exchange_rates.CurrentValue>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>CurrenciesTable</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Currency)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rate)
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Currency)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rate)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Error en línea que dice `@foreach (var item in Model)`:

> System.NullReferenceException: Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías evitar el error agregando esta línea de código en tu vista.

```html
@model IEnumerable<exchange_rates.CurrentValue>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>CurrenciesTable</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Currency)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rate)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Currency)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rate)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Ahora bien, en tu controller está faltando un detalle que no lo estoy pillando.

**EDIT**:
Creo que el problema del controlador podrías verlo así:

```html
namespace exchange_rates.Controllers
{
    public class CurrentValuesController : Controller
    {
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.GetAsync("LA_URL_DE_TU_API");
            var valores = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<CurrentValue>>();
            
            return View(valores);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola @Christian gracias por la ayuda. A qué línea te refieres en la vista? Si no me equivoco, el código es el mismo al que puse yo. 

En cuanto al cambio en el controlador lo he probado y me sigue dando el mismo error en la vista, y además, si cambio como dices de ODataController a Controller me deja de dar servicio